# Cant get original URL of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-search-api

I have been trying to use google custom search api so i can download pictures from it and allow users to use it as their "cover" photo.  Is this even possible?  I can get image search results but they seem to only be thumb nail size:

```
google.load("search", "1", { "nocss": true });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
        function OnLoad() {

            // create a tabbed mode search control
            var tabbed = new google.search.SearchControl();

            //restrict results: search only moderated
            //tabbed.setRestriction(google.search.RESTRICT_SAFESEARCH, google.search.SAFESEARCH_STRICT);

            // Set the Search Control to get the most number of results
            tabbed.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.LARGE_RESULTSET);

            // create image searchers.
            tabbed.addSearcher(new google.search.ImageSearch());


            // proprofscc: On search completeion
            tabbed.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, bind_event);

            // draw in tabbed layout mode
            var drawOptions = new google.search.DrawOptions();
            drawOptions.setDrawMode(google.search.SearchControl.DRAW_MODE_TABBED);

            // Draw the tabbed view in the content div
            tabbed.draw(document.getElementById("googleImageSearch"), drawOptions);

            // Search!
            tabbed.execute("");
        }
        function bind_event() {



            $("a.gs-image").bind("click", function (e) {
                $("#hidden-upload-image").attr("src", $(this).children("img").attr('src'));

                //alert($(this).children("img").attr('src'));

                $("#imageContainer").html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" alt="Loading Image..." />');


                $("a.gs-image img").removeClass();
                $("a.gs-image img").addClass("gs-image");
                $(this).find("img").removeClass();
                $(this).find("img").addClass("selectImage");

                if ($(".gs-imageResult").length <= 0) {
                    $("#gsearchErr").css("display", "block");
                } else {
                    $("#gsearchErr").css("display", "none");
                }

                return false;
            });

            $("div.gsc-cursor").prepend("<div class='clear' style='margin-top:10px;clear:both;'></div>");

            $(".gsc-trailing-more-results").css("display", "none");

        }
```

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

The result object from the image search API has many properties. Check [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide#resultobject) for a complete list. The property you would be interested in is `url`, described as *"Provides the encoded URL to an image file in the result set."*

It's worth noting that the Google Image Search API was officially [deprecated in May 2011](https://developers.google.com/image-search/). If you're working on an application that doesn't already have a legacy of Google Image Search API code, you should instead use the newer [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).